# Nested data-toggle with SASS

Tags: css, button, sass

I was wondering if it was possible to nest data-toggle in SASS. 
Say I have some buttons to make which are the same width and height but the color of each is button is different.

Would it be possible to make them like:

```
[data-toggle]{
   width:150px;
   height:50px;
   &=result{
     background:green;
   }
   &=create{
     background:red;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to nest the selectors in the manner that you've suggested.

One solution is to create a Sass map of `data-toggle` values to background-colors, then use an `@each` loop to iterate over the key-value pairs:

```
// Base styling for elements with the [data-toggle] attribute
[data-toggle] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;  
}

// Generate declarations for colored toggles
$data-toggle-colors: (
  'result': green,
  'create': red
);

@each $color in $data-toggle-colors {
  $key:   nth($color, 1);
  $value: nth($color, 2);

  [data-toggle=#{$key}] {
    background-color: $value;
  }
}
```

**Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lkgxvv**